# Does installing a package install also update an installed package

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I have a shell script, periodically run to keep the Android SDK up to date on my CI server. I am migrating from: `android update sdk --filter <foopackage>` to: `sdkmanager <foopackage>`.

For packages without a `major.minor.patch` in their identifier (e.g. `platform-tools`, `tools`, the `extras;*`) - these would previously be updated implicitly under the previous approach. Reading the docs (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) it is unclear whether `sdkmanager <foopackage>` will update the package if it is already installed, or only install it if it is missing? (in which case an `sdkmanager --update <foopackage>` would also be required)

Comment: As you pass the version in the command `(build-tools;25.0.0)` it will implicitly install the package with that number and won't update it. You will need to run the `update` command for updating them.

Comment: Agreed. I'm interested in what happens to packages which do *not* include the version in their identifier, e.g. platform-tools, extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> The packages argument is an SDK-style path as shown with the --list command, wrapped in quotes (for example, "build-tools;25.0.0" or "platforms;android-25")

The `--list` gives an output something like:

```
Available Packages:
Path                              | Version      | Description                      
-------                           | -------      | -------                          
add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-23 | 1            | Google APIs                      
add-ons;addon-g..._apis-google-24 | 1            | Google APIs                      
add-ons;addon-g...e_gdk-google-19 | 11           | Glass Development Kit Preview    
build-tools;25.0.0                | 25.0.0       | Android SDK Build-Tools 25       
build-tools;25.0.1                | 25.0.1       | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.1   
build-tools;25.0.2                | 25.0.2       | Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2   
cmake;3.6.3155560                 | 3.6.3155560  | CMake 3.6.3155560                
docs                              | 1            | Documentation for Android SDK    
extras;android;gapid;3            | 3.1.0        | GPU Debugging tools              
extras;android;m2repository       | 43.0.0       | Android Support Repository       
extras;google;auto                | 1.1          | Android Auto Desktop Head Unit...
extras;google;play_billing        | 5            | Google Play Billing Library      
extras;google;simulators          | 1            | Android Auto API Simulators      
extras;google;webdriver           | 2            | Google Web Driver                
extras;m2reposi...ut;1.0.0-alpha9 | 1            | ConstraintLayout for Android 1...
extras;m2reposi...out;1.0.0-beta5 | 1            | ConstraintLayout for Android 1...
lldb;2.2                          | 2.2.3271982  | LLDB 2.2                         
ndk-bundle                        | 13.1.3345770 | NDK                              
patcher;v4                        | 1            | SDK Patch Applier v4             
platform-tools                    | 25.0.3       | Android SDK Platform-Tools       
platforms;android-24              | 2            | Android SDK Platform 24          
platforms;android-25              | 3            | Android SDK Platform 25                     
sources;android-25                | 1            | Sources for Android 25           
system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 5            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys...
system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 5            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 3            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys...
system-images;a...gle_apis;x86_64 | 3            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 ...
tools                             | 25.2.5       | Android SDK Tools 25.2.5         

Available Updates:
ID                         | Installed | Available
-------                    | -------   | -------  
extras;google;m2repository | 42        | 43
```

So for updating a package you will need to pass the complete value under `Path`column. For example the following command `sdkmanager "platform-tools"` will update the platform tools as there is no version for it in the `Path`column.

But the command `sdkmanager "build-tools"` will throw an error

> Error: Failed to find package build-tools

So you will need to pass the complete value to install/update a package using the command `sdkmanager <foopackage>`.

However, if you use `sdkmanager --update` it will install the updates for all the packages that are currently installed.

Comment: "sdkmanager "platform-tools" will update the platform tools as there is no version for it in the Pathcolumn." - Are you saying this because it would be a sensible implementation or because you have tested it?

Comment: I have tested it.

Comment: Not trying to be rude - its just the old tool behaved in a bunch of weird ways you would not reasonably expect from reading the docs!

Comment: Use sdkmanager --list --verbose see the names of packages that are too long to show in the list above.